# If $\xi=kx$, does $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}=\frac{d^{2}}{d\xi^{2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $\xi= kx$. Does $\dfrac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}=\dfrac{d^{2}}{d\xi^{2}}$? If so, why? If not, what factor do I need to account for to make this change of variables?

Comment: Surely the factor of $k$ is going to appear from the chain rule... Have you worked out the first order derivative, to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try an example: $y = x^2$, so $\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = 2$.  Now with $\xi = k x$ we have $x = \xi/k$, so $y = \xi^2/k^2$.  Now what is $\dfrac{d^2 y}{d\xi^2}$?

Comment: Well this shows that they are not in fact equal. But I am trying to make sense of an equation I am finding in a textbook: $\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\xi \exp{(-\xi^{2}/2)}=\dfrac{d^2}{d\xi^2}\xi \exp{(-\xi^{2}/2)}$ See [link](https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/kJQzK688Nrs/7QerXch1G4kZlGhy): problem 2.11 for the n=1 case.

Comment: As it stands, that equation makes no sense.

Comment: I've uploaded a link to the pdf I'm looking at. In problem 2.11 (pdf page #21) for the n=1 wave function case the solution seems to do what I've written in the above comment for the calculation of $\langle p^2 \rangle $.

Comment: To be clear: $\xi=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}x$